# Display error when fileupload limit is exceeded

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, file-upload

In my page when I upload a file of size more than 4 MB it shows that the connection was reset. The reason is because the file upload limit is less than 4 MB. 
There is a solution to this  on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2759193/display-custom-error-page-when-file-upload-exceeds-allowed-size-in-asp-net-mvc/3787284#3787284)

But, instead I want to show the error on the same page and not redirect. How can I do this?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/567273/where-do-i-catch-and-handle-maxallowedcontentlength-exceeded-in-iis7

Answer (score 2):

You should read the file size and display errors (or not) before uploading (Saving the file)

```
protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        if(FileUpload1.PostedFile.ContentLength > 4096)
        {
            ErrorLabel.Text = "The file you are trying to upload exceeds the allowed limit.";
        }
        else
        {
            string SavePath = "TheLocationTheFilesSaves";
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(SavePath + FileUpload1.FileName);
            // Do stuff
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Doesn't the error get thrown even when trying to read the size of a file that is over the limit?

Comment: @mccrager : i am looking for a way to display an error message to the user that the file can't be uploaded.

Comment: Not until you try to save it, @mccrager.

Comment: @TheGeekYouNeed can this validation be done through jquery or javascript? If you have any idea.

Comment: The File API with HTML 5 is able to, I believe